# Ubuntu GNOME how to do an applications menu shortcut

Tags: gnome, icons, menu, ubuntu-gnome, appmenu

Let's just say that I want to have a menu like this

[image: Screenshot]

The problem with the applications menu extension is that it removes the opportunity to just click there and go directly to the overwiev of activities. You can just open the applications menu.

How could I create a shortcut to that menu while still having the activities button on the left-side up of the screen ?

Of course, that icon would be located with the rest of icons in a dock or in the same bar, like one of the icons in this picture

[image: Screenshot]